# Compute a triple Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute the triple integral $\int\int\int_{D}fdV$ , where $f(\vec{r})= xy$ and $D$ is the tetrahedron: $D=(\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R^3}, 0 < y < x, |z| < 1 − x)$

This question has puzzled me for a number of hours now so if anyone could help me out that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you drawn the region $D$? The integral with limits is:

$$ \int_0^a \left( \int_0^x \left ( \int_{-(1-x)}^{1-x} xy \, dz\, \right) dy\,\right) dx. $$

Remember that in the second integral, the limits are:

$$ \int_0^x \left (... \right) dy, $$

because $0 < y < x.$

By the way, I think $a=1$ because you need the value of $x$ such as $1-x= -(1-x).$

About the first integral,

$$\int_{-(1-x)}^{1-x} xy \, dz = xy \int_{-(1-x)}^{1-x} dz,$$

because $xy$ are constant and don't depend on $z$.

Comment: Im confused about the 1st integral. how are you meant to integrate xy in terms of z??

Comment: I added more info

Comment: So for the 1st integral do you get $2xy-2x^2y$ as a solution?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: so with the second integral i got $xy^2-x^2y^2$ and with the 3rd integral i got $\frac{y^2}{12}$ is this correct??

Comment: I made a stupid mistake

Comment: what mistake did you make??

Comment: I added the correct info

Comment: ok so for the second integral do you get $\int_{0}^{x}2xy-2x^2ydy=x^{-1}$

Comment: is this correct???

Comment: $$ \int_{0}^x (2xy-2x^2y)\,dy = x^3 - x^4 $$